# Unit test for aggregated spring cloud stream application

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I'm after the unit test for aggregated spring cloud stream app, the main method looks like this :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AggregateApplicationBuilder(MyApplication .class, args)
                .from(MyProcessor.class)
                .via(MyFilterProcessor.class)
                .run();
    }
}
```

In unit test, I'm sending message via processor like below, but **only** `MyProcessor` gets invoked. If I deploy this aggregated app via data flow server , everything works as expected.

Please advise

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
  @SpringBootTest( classes = {
                    MyApplication .class,
                })
  @DirtiesContext
   public class AggTest{
    @Autowired
    private Processor processor;

    @Autowired
    protected MessageCollector messageCollector;

    @Test
      public void testMethod(){
        processor.input().send(message);
        messageCollector.forChannel(processor.output()).poll();
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/723 to track this.

The tested application needs to be set up as an aggregate - the same way as the `main` method does. However, in that case, it doesn't seem to be easy to get ahold of the input channel and send a message. I am afraid this is a blocker, but hopefully we'll fix it soon.